# Converting string to date in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I'm new to Crystal Reports, I'm trying to extract and display month and year from the string (In DB the data type of the column is varchar). Following is an example of the data.

> 05-JAN-12 11.49.28.000000000 AM

I need it in following format

> Jan-12

I have used [cDate](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic728.html) to convert the string to date format but was unsuccessful, maybe I didn't do it right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the formula to extract the date portion, then convert it to a `date`:

```
DateValue(Split("05-JAN-12 11.49.28.000000000 AM")[1])
```

Apply formatting to the field as desired.

Comment: +1 Only offered solution that actually works and converts to a date datatype.

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
Date (Year ({reportfield}) * 10000 + Month ({reportfield}) * 100 + Day ({reportfield}))
```

Then format the field to display the date as your choosing.

Answer (score -1):

```
MonthName(DatePart ("m", <<Date field>>))+"-"+totext(DatePart ("yyyy", <<DAtefield>>),0,"")
```