# Convert string to date Bad date format string error 'DateValue'

Tags: string, date, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a formula that converts string to date.

```
DateValue("ORDERCHECK.LOTNUMBER")
```

And It's giving me `Bad date format string`error

`ORDERCHECK`is the table & `LOTNUMBER` is the field

I've looked a lot into this and still no luck.
Any advice would be highly appreciated!

My good reference has been [Converting string to date in crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658847/converting-string-to-date-in-crystal-reports)

Comment: and lotnumber is in date format?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu It is in the mixture of date and machine number

Comment: I think you got a duplicate case here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190570/1385774

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced conversion of a single number to year, along with hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143964/advanced-conversion-of-a-single-number-to-year-along-with-hyphen)

Answer (score 0):

"ORDERCHECK.LOTNUMBER" is in the form of (mm-dd-y-abcd)

ex) y = 7 = 2-17

therefore, CR thinks it's not in the right date form.